# Change $TMPDIR in a parallel processing

Tags: hpc, gnu-parallel, slurm

I run a batch job on a high-performance computing system to sort aligned reads and used GNU parallel to speed up my work, but my job failed with the following reason:

> parallel: Error: Output is incomplete. Cannot append to buffer file in
>   $TMPDIR. Is the disk full? parallel: Error: Change $TMPDIR with
>   --tmpdir or use --compress.

My job script looks like this:

```
module load samtools/1.2

export TMPDIR=/scratch/$SLURM_JOBID

cd /data
ls *sam* | parallel "samtools sort –T /scratch/$SLURM_JOBID/{.} -O bam -o {}.bam {}"
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

I get the same message “parallel: Error: Change $TMPDIR with --tmpdir or use --compress”

I try adding "--tmpdir /home/mydirectory" to the script, but when I see the file "/home/mydirectory/" doesn’t create anything, I see the default directory "/tmp/" and the temporally files (like /tmp/pAh6uWuQCg, /tmp/opjhZCzAX4, etc) are still created in that directory. For me it means that the parameter “--tmpdir /home/mydirectory” in the script does not work.

In my case I run the script of my app isolated and check the logs, and realize that my app was with error, for that the logs shows error messages and it was fill the file "/tmp/"

Maybe my experience will help you

Comment: I have also found that when I see this error, usually some component of my script is generating an unexpected amount of output. In my case it was something that needed to be piped and wasn't. The feature works as expected in GNU Parallel.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried what GNU Parallel suggests?

```
parallel: Error: Change $TMPDIR with --tmpdir or use --compress.
```

Comment: I have already tried this:

ls *sam* | parallel --compress --tmpdir /scratch/$SLURM_JOBID "samtools sort –T /scratch/$SLURM_JOBID/{.} -O bam -o {}.bam {}"

But it still doesn’t work.

Comment: But is /scratch/$SLURM_JOBID big enough for that? Can you use another dir where there is more space available? GNU Parallel is trying to tell you that free space is too small.

Comment: I allocated 500 GB for /scratch/$SLURM_JOBID. Do you think my code for changing and setting $TMPDIR is correct or not?

export TMPDIR=/scratch/$SLURM_JOBID

ls *sam* | parallel --compress --tmpdir /scratch/$SLURM_JOBID "samtools sort –T /scratch/$SLURM_JOBID/{.} -O bam -o {}.bam {}"

Comment: I think the 500 GB is too little. Can you set TMPDIR to a dir where you have more space available and test that it fixes the problem? Or at least try running a single job at a time (-j1) to see if that fixes it?

Comment: @OleTange: I will try your advice. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still interested in the answer,

`export TMPDIR=/scratch/$SLURM_JOBID` should work. The only problem might be the new TMPDIR is also small and disk is really full. Try a different directory. It worked for me.